# Custom function is calculating incorrect mean. Unable to locate the problem in the code

Tags: r, function, for-loop, mean

I have recently began to learn R. I have written a function named 'pollutantmean' that calculates the mean of a pollutant (sulfate or nitrate) across a specified list of monitors. The function 'pollutantmean' takes three arguments: 'directory', 'pollutant', and 'id'. Given a vector monitor ID numbers, 'pollutantmean' reads that monitors' particulate matter data from the directory specified in the 'directory' argument and returns the mean of the pollutant across all of the monitors, ignoring any missing values coded as NA.

I have written the following function, but it is calculating the wrong mean. I am unable to locate the problem.

```
Pollutantmean <- function(directory, pollutant, id=1:332) {
  directory <- setwd("C:/Users/raza zaidi/Desktop/Data_Science/New_Rproject/specdata")
  
  # Created an empty data.frame
  databox <- data.frame()
  
  # Used loop function to read through all csv files
  for (data_files in list.files(pattern= "*.csv")) {
    allcsv <- read.csv(data_files, header = TRUE)
  }
  
  # I combined all csv files into single object
  combined_data <- rbind(databox, allcsv)
  pollutant <- combined_data[, c("sulfate", "nitrate")]
  subset_df <- subset(combined_data, select = c("ID"))
  
  # Filtered the rows of the data frame to include only the specified id values
  subset_df <- subset(subset_df, id %in% ID)
  total <- sum(pollutant, na.rm = TRUE)
  
  # Computed the mean of the pollutant values
  mean_value <- total / length(id)
  
  # Return the mean value
  return(mean_value)
}
```

If we run following function

```
pollutantmean("specdata", "sulfate", 1:10)
```

the answere should be following

```
[1] 4.064128
```

But I am getting

```
[1] 2.3275
```

I am unable to figure out the mistake in my computation. Can anyone assist me in finding the problem?

If we run following function

```
pollutantmean("specdata", "sulfate", 1:10)
```

the answere should be following

```
[1] 4.064128
```

But I am getting

```
[1] 2.3275
```

Comment: This must be the “homework problem that will not die”. If you doubt me then try a SO search on “[r] pollutant csv”

Answer (score 1):

Seeing the data or minimal reproducible example would have been helpful to check your "should have been" answer.

But, from looking at the code issues is most likely due to `NA` values. You are ignoring them in calculation of `sum` but not of `length`

```
> x <- rnorm(10)
> x[c(1, 5)] <- NA_real_
> sum(x, na.rm = TRUE) / length(x)
[1] 0.8789583
> mean(x, na.rm = TRUE)
[1] 1.098698
> sum(x, na.rm = TRUE) / length(x[!is.na(x)])
[1] 1.098698
```

Also there are several other problems in your code:

1. `directory` is passed as the function argument but is also overwritten in the first line.
2. `databox` is redundant.
3. `allcsv` is overwritten each iteration of the loop. So, it doesn't read all files, but just the last one. (This will also effect your expected results)
4. `sum(pollutant, na.rm = TRUE)` takes a sum of dataframe with two columns. Maybe not an expected behavior. (This will also effect your expected results)

```
> df = data.frame(a = 1:3, b = 1:3)
> sum(df)
[1] 12
> colSums(df)
a b 
6 6
```

Answer (score 0):

**solution**

```
pollutantmean <- function(directory, pollutant, id) {
  mean(unlist(lapply(sprintf("%2$s/%03d.csv", id, directory), \(file) {
    read.csv(file, header = TRUE)[, pollutant]
  })), na.rm = TRUE)
}

pollutantmean("specdata", "sulfate", 1:10)

# [1] 4.0641
```

**Ok, now I did your homework, but I hope you read further.**

`directory <- setwd("C:/Users/raza zaidi/Desktop/Data_Science/New_Rproject/specdata")`

You are supposed to pass `directory` in the function, you have a hardcoded path. In my approach I assume the data directory in the same directory as your script, but you can use any path there.

`list.files(pattern= "*.csv")` is usually a good way to get **all** files from a folder, but here it is more wise to only get the list of files you are going to need.

`sprintf` is powerfull for this, especially since you also want to pass the zero-padded numbers.

```
sprintf("%2$s/%03d.csv", 1:5, "specdata")
# [1] "specdata/001.csv" "specdata/002.csv" "specdata/003.csv" "specdata/004.csv" "specdata/005.csv"
```

Above does the same as for example `paste0("specdata", "/", str_pad(1:5, 3, "left", "0"), ".csv")`

Then you want to "loop" over your files, in your attempt you only keep the data of your last file. A good approach is to use lapply here to loop over files as every result is part of the list.

As we are only interested in 1 value in the file, we directly can subset using `read.csv(file, header = TRUE)[, pollutant]` so what happens here is that the whole file is read as a data.table and we only pick the values of the column of interest.

We simply unlist the outcome of the lapply, to make one vector of values you want to calculate the mean over and you are done.